# Web API Testing: In-Memory Hosting using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-api-testing

I have been using the HttpClient to set up my Web API test. It's very cool in that you can have the HttpClient either make a call over the wire(actually hit a remote resource) or host your server in-memory and actually call it internally. Great flexibility. I have encountered one problem:

```
using (HttpSelfHostConfiguration config2 = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration
("http://localhost:47620/"))
{
config2.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new 
{id=RouteParameter.Optional });
server = new HttpServer(config2);
httpClient = new HttpClient(server);
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:47620/");

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("api/values/5", UriKind.Relative));
var version = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The HttpClient allows me to invoke tests over the wire OR in memory as shown above. Running them over the wire works great. But, when I run them in memory(example above), the test does hit the controller as expected, but inside the controller, if a app.config value is needed, it's null.

Does anyone know how to get the in-memory host for HttpClient to respect your app config? Seems like a huge hole if this isn't possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a mocking framework like `RhinoMocks` to mock out your Configuration?

Comment: I am not. I was hoping that since the in-memory invocation is able to host the controller code, I assumed it would respect the web.config values as well. Seems crazy that you have to add mocks to get it to work.

Comment: Once you understand it, no, not crazy at all -- but yes, it can seem that way before you realize that spinning up the web.config is part of the IIS pipeline

Comment: Sure. I suppose. But the object you create for this to work is called HttpServer....which is what IIS is. :) I can't even configure the HttpServer object manually to read the config so I think you are correct in that I'll have to mock out my controllers. Sigh.